# A question about the sentence structures of the following examples

Tags: sentence-construction, style, sentence-choice

I need help in choosing between the constructs 'is' and 'to be'

I am trying to say:

Now that I have argued that there is a research need, I would like to fill something of a gap by  . . .

The choices:

> Having established what I argued **to be** a lack in research, I seek to
>   . . .
>   Having established what I argued **is** lack in research, I seek
>   . . .

Would one is more digestible?

Comment: I think either is OK, though the second one needs an article "what I argued is ***a*** lack in research".

Answer (score 1):

I don't like either one.  The word **lack** should be followed by **of** and not **in**.

Answer (score 0):

I think both the sentences are indigestible.

When we use the word "lack" as a noun, we usually say "lack of/a lack of".  However, we use "lack in" when lack is used as a verb. So, the correct sentence is "Having established what I argued is a lack of research, I seek......".